# Python with Visual Studio Code on Mac

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Trying to figure out Python with Visual Studio on Mac. Dependencies and Libraries don't seem to install/launch correctly.

For example, I have pandas on my system, installed via pip, and if I do

```
import pandas as pd
```

from a Python prompt, it works fine.

With Visual Studio Code, if I create a file with the above code, autocomplete recognizes that pandas is installed

[image: Autocomplete recognizes pandas is installed]

When I try to run, I get an ImportError: No module named pandas

[image: VS Code Error]

Any ideas?

Update: It works in VSCode's terminal, just not when I run the code in the debugger.

[image]

Comment: I had this problem before, and it was because I was using a conda executable and VS Code didn't know what packages I had installed. Did you specify the correct python executable in your configuration?

Comment: I woudl suggest to test what version is running in VSCode, in my case by default it was 2.7.

Comment: Installed the plugins that VS Code prompted, which gave me 2.7.14 and the Python linter.

Comment: And what version is python prompt you test it?

Comment: When using VS Code's terminal I get:

Laurences-iMac:tf lmoroney$ pythonPython 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 12:01:12)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwinType "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: how are you running your python script?

Comment: When I get the error, I'm pressing F5 in Visual Studio Code

Comment: The first step is making sure that VS Code picked up the interpreter you expect. So if you do step #3 of the [tutorial prerequisites](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_prerequisites) you will see the instructions on how to explicitly select the interpreter. After that you can write a file that does nothing but `import pandas; print "It worked!"`, right-click, and select `Run Python File in Terminal`. If that didn't work then you didn't install pandas for the Python interpreter you thought you did. If that works but debugging fails then your `launch.json` might be off.

Comment: Ah! Step 3 there -- selecting the interpreter -- seemed to do the trick. I picked the latest (2.7.14) and pandas was present. I then tried to run with another library (tensorflow) and it failed, but a pip install tensorflow within the Code terminal then worked. That seems to have done it -- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laurence Moroney is right -- this issue occurs when VS Code is using a Python interpreter different from the one that has your libraries installed.

See [Configuring Python Environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) for instructions on changing the interpreter globally in VS Code. Don't forget to restart VS Code afterwards.